# Characters < and > in sprintf()

Tags: php, printf

I have a trivial problem in PHP but I can't seem to find an explanation for this.

I have a simple `sprintf` to compose an email header:

```
$mail_to = sprintf('%s %s <%s>', 'Harry', 'Potter', 'h.potter@example.com');
```

But this just stores `Harry Potter` and seems to ignore anything contained between `<` and `>` characters. Removing `<` and `>` correctly yields `Harry Potter h.potter@example.com`.

I checked the PHP manual for the function but it doesn't mention any issue regarding these characters. I also tried to escape them with `%` as suggested in similar questions but it wouldn't seem to need escaping.

Obviously I can chain simple strings using `.` to achieve this and probably will do so. But still I'm curious as for why this happens.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Not reproducible: https://3v4l.org/8Xpcf

Comment: What PHP version are you running? I can't reproduce this in PHP 7.1

Comment: Neither in 4.x, 5.x or 7.x ...

Comment: Btw, don't you check the output in browser? Where `< ... >` is treated as a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what's happening is that your browser (Chrome, IE, Sarafi, etc), thinks that the thing between the brackets is a HTML tag. Try this:

```
$mail_to = sprintf('%s %s &lt;%s&gt;', 'Harry', 'Potter', 'h.potter@example.com');
```

See if that works.

Comment: Yea, my bad. This gets outputted to a page and it gets treated like a tag. Forgive the trivial mistake and thanks for your answer!

Comment: @GigiSan if the answer helped you should check it mark as solution of the question

Comment: @MaximFedorov I'm well aware of that, I'm waiting for the 10 minutes timer :)